# Battery Time Remaining not displayed anymore after update to Big Sur on 2014 Macbook Pro

Tags: battery, software-update

I recently updated my 2014 MacBook (MacBook Pro Retina, 13') from Catalina to Big Sur. The battery info in the bar on the top doesn't display the battery time remaining anymore.

Online I only found suggestions for installing additional software, which I would like to avoid.
Is there some way to regain this information?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Catalina doesn't display this information.

Apple removed the time display as of Sierra (10.12).  Only the percentage is available.

https://osxdaily.com/2016/12/13/macos-sierra-10-12-2-update-available/

> MacOS Sierra 10.12.2 also removes the “battery time remaining” indicator from Mac laptops, apparently in response to some complaints about unsatisfactory battery life on 2016 model year MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. The time remaining battery estimator has been part of Mac OS X for over 15 years, but now Mac laptop users will have no automatic battery life estimate offered by the system software after installing Mac OS 10.12.2.

Answer (score 1):

Command space > activity monitor > energy

[image: time remaining]

Answer (score -3):

I assume you mean the little battery and percentage.

Try this :

- Click on Apple logo (top left of screen)
- System Preferences
- Dock & Menu Bar
  The Dock & Menu bar section has a menu on the left :
- scroll to "Other Modules"
- Click on "Battery (Menu bar and control centre)"
- on the right pane - tick the boxes :

  - Show in Menu bar
  - Show in Control centre
  - Show percentage

Hope that helps ..

(hint : in system preferences there is a search in the top right, try typing "battery" - should lead you there)